# How many years is considered long term drug/medication usage

Tags: medications

Patients tend to worry about the side effects that may be caused by longterm drug/meds usage. How many years do you have to consume the drug/meds to say that you are longterm on it? Likewise, if you get off the drug for let's say a couple of months or one year and then start again, is the "longterm" word meaning disrupted?

**Example**: I've been taking PPIs (proton pump inhibitors) for 5 years, but the first year I've taken them for 2 months, second year 2 months, third year 1 month, fourth year less than a month and fifth year 4 months on and off. Am I a longterm user of the drug or not?

Comment: "Longterm use" is not an absolute term, although it might be defined one way or another in a given study. In order to meaningfully answer this question I think it needs to be about one drug or drug class (PPIs would be fine) and a particular outcome that you think might ensue due to "longterm use". We could then (attempt to) find research about what the time course of developing such outcome actually is.

Comment: I see, tnx for the comment. I got a clearer view now. It would be nice if you could extend your comment to form a decent answer.

Comment: I don't know personally. Approved dosing charts seem necessary to use any medication appropriately and safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have been on the PPI's long term. Not to be confused with continuous long-term, which is because you broke the cycle several times in the five years. Criteria;

- Taking them for 5 years
- Taking them for a month or almost a month
- Taking them for a reason that may not go away(not sure, but if the condition is chronic then you will need the meds chronic/longterm) signifying that you will continue to need them

[Medscape:](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/820136_2)

> a definition in the literature for "long-term" is lacking; neither the
>   AGA guidelines nor the ACG guidelines define what is considered
>   long-term. For the rest of this article, the authors use long-term to
>   designate therapy greater than 14 days

So we can deduce that if you continue therapy for longer than 14 days every year you will be long term.

[About.GERD.com](http://www.aboutgerd.org/site/treatment/medications/ppi)

> Be aware that the OTC proton pump inhibitors should only be used as
>   directed for 14 days for the treatment of frequent heartburn. If your
>   heartburn continues, talk to your healthcare professional. No more
>   than three 14-day treatment courses should be used in one year.

So from here we can see that PPI's here are only indicated for around 14 days 3 times a year.

[Are Heartburn Medications Safe for Long-Term Use?](http://www.everydayhealth.com/digestive-health/experts-are-heartburn-medications-safe.aspx)

[Approved dosing chart for how long to take and amount of PPI](https://www.cms.gov/Medicare-Medicaid-Coordination/Fraud-Prevention/Medicaid-Integrity-Education/Pharmacy-Education-Materials/Downloads/ppi-adult-dosingchart11-14.pdf)